# Handling exception in antlr4 parser

Tags: parsing, syntax, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I have a grammar that should allow a parametrized 'cast' but not a parametrized 'literal'. This is just a way of saying:

- `VARCHAR(5) "Hello There"` --> BAD
- `"Hello There"::VARCHAR(5)` --> GOOD

My thought is actually that I should allow the literal parametrization within the antlr4 grammar, so that it can accurately be caught and provide a good error message, such as:

> Direct literal parametrization is not supported, did you mean `"Hello There"::VARCHAR(5)`? If so, [click here](http://example.com) and we'll make the adjustment for you.

Or, should I just not allow it in my grammar rules at all? In other words, should the rule be:

```
literal_loose
  : TYPE ( "(" Params? ")" )? STRING_LITERAL
  ;
```

And the error messaging is done beyond that, or should the rule be:

```
literal_strict
  : TYPE STRING_LITERAL
  ;
```

My thought is the first way would be a much better experience, but then again, it's almost like "adding bad syntax" to the grammar just as a sort of work-around (unless maybe that's how production parsers work in the real world...).

Comment: If you can add the bad syntax without causing ambiguity and that lets you produce better error messages, then I'd say "go for it". Although error messages like that usually make me-as-a-user want to scream: "if you can figure that out, why don't you just accept it??!!?" :-)

Comment: @rici -- ha, there'd be a checkmark afterwards that say "Automatically do this conversion for me next time" :)